# WKWebViewでのローカルHTMLの読み込みについて

Tags: swift, ios

UIWebViewからWKWebViewに移行しようと思い、コードを書き換えていたのですが、WKWebViewでのローカルに置いたHTMLファイルが読み込まれません。UIWebViewでは下記のコードでローカルファイルを読み込むことができました。

```
let cachePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] + "cacheHtml.html"
            try! html.write(toFile: cachePath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: cachePath)!)
            webview.loadRequest(request)
```

上記ではキャッシュディレクトリのパスをとって、String型のhtml変数にwebページのソースが格納されているので、それを書き込んでいます。書き込み後、UIWebViewのloadRequestで読み込んでいます。一方、WKWebViewで下記のように実装したところ、画面が真っ白なまま読み込まれません。

```
let cachePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] + "cacheHtml.html"
            try! html.write(toFile: cachePath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let cacheUrl = URL(string: cachePath)
            let request = URLRequest(url: cacheUrl!)
            webview.load(request)
```

WKWebViewでは、urlをそのまま入れたときや、webview.loadHTMLStringではうまくページを読み込みます。wkwebviewでローカルHTMLファイルを読み込むようにするにはどのように実装したら良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記のようにすることでローカルファイルを読むことができました。

```
let tmpPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("tmpHtml.html") as URL
            try! trimHtml.write(to: tmpPath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            webview.loadFileURL(tmpPath, allowingReadAccessTo: tmpPath)
```

また、webview.load(request(url: tmpPath))でも読み込むことができました。

Comment: http://qiita.com/ShingoFukuyama/items/eede79a284c3669846e9 なんかを見るにtmp内のファイルならload(request)でも読めるようですね。よく確認せずに回答してすみません。

Answer (score 0):

iOS9以上なら`loadFileURL(_ URL: URL, allowingReadAccessTo readAccessURL: URL)`メソッドを使用できます。
もしもiOS8以下に対応するならhtmlをStringに読み込んで`loadHTMLString(_ string: String, baseURL: URL?)`メソッドで読み込むしかありません。

Comment: ご解答ありがとうございます。早速wkwebviewでwebview.load(request)
のところをwebview.loadHTMLString(cacheUrl!, allowingReadAccessTo: cacheUrl!)として実行したところ、is not a file URLとエラーが出ました。引数をどのように設定したら良いでしょうか。

Comment: 上の回答を見るに解決したということでいいでしょうか？